# Error cloning remote repo 'origin' jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

When i try to create a pipeline job through source code management by copying the repo url and then i started building the job but i'm getting this error as error cloning remote repo origin.If any could help me out with the whole process will be much helpful..

I tried to do cicd pipeline task by changing the code in scm and wanted the build to be automatic when the code is committed.

Comment: Why is the error showing up? If you provide  the full error trace we can get a better idea.

Comment: What is the error? And where are you running it? Is it jenkins? AWS code deploy? Gitlab? Please update your answer with more details